# How to use Galois LFSR to find multiplicative inverses

Tags: finite-field, lfsr

My question is how can a Galois Linear Feedback Shift Register be used to discover multiplicative inverses of polynomials?

This is a homework assignment. Here is a list of things I did before asking here:

- Learned about finite fields
- Learned how to do modular arithmetic with polynomials
- Learned about multiplicative inverses in Galois extension fields
- Simulated several different LFSRs on paper
- Plowed through all of my course material

I've got nothing.

Comment: Hint: if $S_0$ is the initial state of a Galois LFSR with polynomial $P$, then after $i$ steps the state is $S_i=S_0\,x^i\bmod P$.

Comment: Is there supposed to be some really simple and obvious way to find the multiplicative inverse? The way I interpret your answer is that I'm supposed to simulate the LFSR until the state equals 1, and then I need to calculate what x is, after which I need to calculate x^i mod P. This seems much more difficult than finding the inverse without the LFSR.

Comment: _"Calculating what $x$ is"_ has no meaning; $x$ is purely notational. You guessed roughly half of the simple method I suggest. Hint2: the LFSR itself can then be used to compute $x^i\bmod P$ knowing $i$.